# Joining Ethereum Contracts with Polygon Contracts

Tags: polygon, polygon-bridge

Our Project consists of 5 Ethereum Contracts

- one Mintable ERC721
- the others are function libraries and data storage. these are triggered from the mintable ERC721 contract.

We now want to bring the function libraries and data storage to Polygon, in order to reduce the gas fees

Which Polygon protocol would make the most sense for this usecase?
Any tips or examples are welcome!

Thank you!